# Display menu in a Telegram bot with PHP when respond to a message

Tags: bots, telegram

I am using PHP and Heroku for a Telegram bot. I have seen other questions but they are mostly using frameworks, and I am not using any framework

This is a part of the code that I am using to reply a simple text to the user:

```php
                    case '/whoami':
                {
                    $_text = "Your ID: ".$user_id;
                    $this->sendMessage([
                        'chat_id' => $chat_id,
                        'text' => $_text
                    ]);
                    break;
                }
```

How can I respond by displaying a menu and not a text message?
Should the `$_text` be in a certain format or structure?

> UPDATE : The code bellow worked for me

```
          $replyMarkup = array(
              'keyboard' => array(
                  array("A", "B")
              )
          );
          $encodedMarkup = json_encode($replyMarkup);
          $this->sendMessage([
              'chat_id' => $chat_id,
              'reply_markup' => $encodedMarkup,
              'text' => $content
          ]);
```

Now in addition to the text content it also brings up a menu for the user on the Telegram app.

Comment: Depends on how your `sendMessage()` function looks like, but I'll suggest you start by reading there [docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) and the `reply_markup` on the `sendMessage` method.

Comment: will do thanks for your help :)

Comment: thanks it solved it for me:) all the best

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferable that you answer your own question with the solution and explaining it, instead of editing the question with the answer/code worked for your case. Have a nice journey on Stack Overflow!